# Manipulate for probability distribution with multiple parameters, kernel smoothing

Tags: manipulate

I'm looking to use the `Manipulate` command to take a distribution with multiple parameters (e.g., mean and sigma for the normal), generate some variates, then plot the density with kernel smoothing. Ideally I'd like to have sliders for all parameters, the number of variates used, and the bandwidth for smoothing.

Here's what I've got:

```
Manipulate[
  Plot[
    SmoothKernelDistribution[RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[μ, σ], numbVars], bw],
    {x, -5, 5}],
  {μ, -1, 1},
  {σ, 0, 5},
  {numVars, 10, 1000, 10},
  {bw, .1, 5}]
```

But it looks like I'm not indicating things correctly, getting errors for the `RandomVariate` parameters and for `SmoothKernelDistribution` and perhaps others that are supressed.

Comment: Welcome to our site, Matt!  I would like to suggest that first you read our [faq] and then respond to its suggestions by showing what you have done so far (with examples of your code). Otherwise your question might be (mis?)interpreted as a request for free coding services, which is not what this community is about.

Comment: @whuber No problem I figured someone might already done something similar, I'll share what I've got so far.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Something like the following should get you started.  I use `KernelMixtureDistribution` with the setting `MaxMixtureKernels` set to `All` because it works symbolically and is not an approximation to the kernel density estimator like `SmoothKernelDistribution`.

```
Manipulate[
 Block[{data, dist, kmd},
  SeedRandom[1];
  data = RandomVariate[dist = NormalDistribution[μ, σ], n];
  kmd = KernelMixtureDistribution[data, h, MaxMixtureKernels -> All];
  Plot[{PDF[dist, x], PDF[kmd, x]}, {x, -xRng, xRng}, PlotRange -> All]
  ]
  , {{μ, 0}, -1, 1}, {{σ, 1}, 0.01, 
  5}, {{n, 100}, {10, 100, 1000, 10000}}, {{xRng, 5}, 1, 
  10}, {{h, .5}, 0.01, 1}
]
```

[image]

Note that in Mathematica these nonparametric density estimators are actually distributions so we need to plot the `PDF` not just the distribution itself.  The benefit is that all other distribution properties like random number generation work too.

Comment: Hi Andy thanks for the solution! What do I change to get the variates to be resampled when I make a change to the sliders?

Comment: Remove the `SeedRandom[1]`.  I put it there specifically to fix the random numbers so it doesn't bounce around when you move any slider.